# Strong law of large numbers for covariance matrix estimation

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

Assume we are given $n$ i.i.d. samples $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ of a random vector $X$ with mean 0 and (true) covariance matrix bounded in norm. Does the standard covariance matrix estimator

$$n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^{\top}$$

converge almost surely to the true covariance matrix? I would like to apply Kolmogorv's strong law of large numbers, but all the literature I found only considers univariate random variables explicitly.

Does it also hold for matrices? Could you then please also provide me literature for this?

Comment: Convergence of  a sequence of matrices is equivalent to covergence of each of its entries.

Comment: I disagree. Here, the entries are dependent and individual almost sure converge does in general not imply joint almost sure convergence!

Comment: Why not?$\phantom{}$

Comment: See "Asymptotic Statistics", p.10 by A. W. van der Vaart. Here it only says that individual convergence implies joint convergence for convergence in probability, which is weaker than almost sure converge. Please provide a reference if you know about a result for almost sure convergence.

Comment: Try to prove it, it is not difficult. :)

Comment: I agree. The measure where two variables do not converge almost surely jointly if they do so individually should trivially be 0, no? I am just confused that this result is not stated somewhere. Maybe it is too trivial.